# PHP check value against multiple values with OR-operator

Tags: php, if-statement, comparison

I have a filename(`$fname`) and I need to assign `$pClass` to the file type with a "-" afterwards. Currently I always get `text-`, no matter what file type it is.

```
//This gets the extention for the file and assigns the class to the icon <i>
$pieces = explode('.', $fname);
$ext = array_pop($pieces);

if($ext == (('txt')||('rtf')||('log')||('docx'))){
  $pClass = 'text-';
}
else if($ext == (('zip')||('sitx')||('7z')||('rar')||('gz'))){
  $pClass = 'archive-';
}
else if($ext == (('php')||('css')||('html')||('c')||('cs')||('java')||('js')||('xml')||('htm')||('asp'))){
  $pClass = 'code-';
}
else if($ext == (('png')||('bmp')||('dds')||('gif')||('jpg')||('psd')||('pspimage')||('tga')||('svg'))){
  $pClass = 'image-';
}
else {
  $pClass = '';
}
```

Why doesn't my if statement with the OR operator works?

Comment: First debug by checking what the value of $ext is being set to

Comment: I just rechecked and $ext is being set correctly for each file (example.php returns "php")

Comment: (('txt')||('rtf')||('log')||('docx')) will always evaluate to 1 and only then be compared to $ext

Comment: Your initial `if` will always return true, hence why you're always getting `test-` back.

Comment: Solutions don't belong in questions. For that we have answers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [logical  `||`(OR) operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) doesn't work as you expect it to work. The `||` operator always evaluates to a boolean either TRUE or FALSE. So in your example your strings get converted into booleans and then compared.

If statement:

```
if($ext == ('txt' || 'rtf'|| 'log' || 'docx'))
```

Comes down to:

```
if($ext == (TRUE || TRUE || TRUE || TRUE))
if($ext == TRUE)
```

---

To solve this problem and get the code to work as you want it to you can use different methods.

## Multiple comparison

One way to solve the problem and check your values against multiple values is, to actually compare the value against multiple values:

```
if($ext == "txt" || $ext == "rtf" /* || ... */)
```

## [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Another way is to use the function `in_array()` and check if the value is equal to one of the array values:

```
if(in_array($ext, ["txt", "rtf" /* , ... */], TRUE))
```

<sub>Note: Second parameter is for strict comparison</sub>

## [`switch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

You could also use `switch` to check your value against multiple values and just let the case fall through.

```
switch($ext){

    case "txt":
    case "rtf":
 /* case ...: */
        $pClass = "text-";
    break;

}
```

Comment: Please tell me we have a good duplicate for this :)? Otherwise we just create it right here right now.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go try this now

Comment: That works great, Thanks for the help showing how to do it the right way

Answer (score 2):

I would simply change it to something like this:

```
//This gets the extention for the file and assigns the class to the icon <i>
$pieces = explode('.', $fname);
$ext = array_pop($pieces);
if(in_array($ext,array('txt','rtf','log','docx'))){
    $pClass = 'text-';
}elseif(in_array($ext,array('zip','sitx','7z','rar','gz'))){
    $pClass = 'archive-';
}elseif(in_array($ext,array('php','css','html','c','cs','java','js','xml','htm','asp'))) {
    $pClass = 'code-';
}elseif(in_array($ext,array('png','bmp','dds','gif','jpg','psd','pspimage','tga','svg'))){
    $pClass = 'image-';
}else {
    $pClass = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in_array()` to compare a value to multiple strings:

```
if(in_array($ext, array('txt','rtf','log','docx')){
    // Value is found.
}
```