# Is there a way to pass this CSV value across to another PHP file by clicking the value in HTML?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to pass a CSV index, the first entry on each line of CSV to another CSV file to display the full line. On this page I'm only showing a few details about each item in my library system and when you click on the according anchor which says "1" or "2" to another PHP file. This is the code for both of the files.

This is for the list with limited information per item.

```
<?php

if (($handle = fopen("ModuleData.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $x = 0;

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $value = $data[0]; // Get the value from the CSV

        // Encode the value to be URL-safe
        $encodedValue = urlencode($value);

        // Generate the URL with the encoded value
        $url = "display.php?clicked=" . $encodedValue;

        // Output the anchor tag with the URL
        echo "<a href='$url'>" . $data[0] . "</a>  -  " . $data[3] . "  -  " . $data[5] . "<br><br>";
        $x = $x + 3;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

This is for the file which displays all the information on the line depending on which index value it is given.

```
<?php

$desired = isset($_POST['index']) ? $_POST['index'] : '';
$passed = $_GET['clicked'];
$f = fopen("ModuleData.csv", "r");
$i = 0; // Sets default line to index 0
while ($line = fgets($f)) {
    if ($i == $desired || $passed) {
        $line = str_replace(",", "<br>", $line); // Replace commas with line breaks
        echo $line;
        break;
    }
    ++$i; // Increments until line is the one desired by input
}
fclose($f);
?>
```

I was expecting that it would pass the value across from the list.php file to the display.php file but it doesn't seem to be the case. I am very new to PHP and trying to learn so a solution and explanation would help.

What happened with this method is it will pass the value 0 when every index number is clicked except when 0 is clicked then it will pass no value at all, I assume it would pass the value array to it but I'm not sure. It will display the correct line when manually inputted using the input form in display.php but I'm struggling to pass the first value on each line to this file as a shortcut.

Comment: You are using a GET request, but trying to retrieve the data using `$_POST`. Where is `index` being passed from?

Comment: The post request is for a form input above, the get request is meant to grab the index number from another page so the user doesn't have to input it manually and remember the index. But the post lets them input it manually on the other page. If that makes sense.   Index is being passed through a line of code above in HTML    <label for="index"></label><input class="text-input" name="index" id="index" type="number" placeholder="Enter Index Number"/><br>

Comment: Hang on are you trying to check the POST and GET value at the very same time? If not then separate the logic using an `if` condition using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` and just keep a single variable say `$desired` which would have values from either POST or GET request or default 0

Comment: Oh that doesn't seem to be the issue whenever I pass it 0 it will automatically display index 0 line with all the information which can then be overwritten by a manual entry, its just the passing it of other values other than just 0. I will try your solution for that tho. ty

Comment: Or make your form use `GET` instead of POST and name your form input `clicked` so you end up with the same URL from your form and clicking the link

Comment: `if ($i == $desired || $passed)` - that doesn't do what you thought it does, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36971869/1427878

Comment: "for a form input above" - can you share the code involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I passed the variable type via the url using an anchor and redirect which echos when any of the entries in the list are clicked. One thing I found out though is that the url auto lowercases everything put through it so try not to miss the $_GET by using an uppercase character. I also removed the boolean OR (Silly mistake on my half it was quite late for me when writing it) and just placed it in a if statement where it checks if the manual input had any input prior to the redirect. I just did this by checking to see if the $desired variable was true (not empty).

Here is the fixed code:

List.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
if (($handle = fopen("ModuleData.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $value = $data[0]; // Get the value from the CSV
        $sendData = '<a href="display.php?send=' . $value . '">' . $data[0] . '</a>';
        // Output the anchor tag with the URL
        echo $sendData . " -  " . $data[3] . "  -  " . $data[5] . "<br><br>";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Display.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$passed = $_GET['send'];
$desired = isset($_POST['index']) ? $_POST['index'] : '';

if ($desired) {
    $f = fopen("ModuleData.csv", "r");
    $i = 0; // Sets default line to index 0
    while ($line = fgets($f)) {
        if ($i == $desired) {
            $line = str_replace(",", "<br>", $line); // Replace commas with line breaks
            echo $line;
            break;
        }
        ++$i; // Increments until line is the one desired by input
    }
    fclose($f);
}

else{
    $f = fopen("ModuleData.csv", "r");
    $i = 0; // Sets default line to index 0
    while ($line = fgets($f)) {
        if ($i == $passed) {
            $line = str_replace(",", "<br>", $line); // Replace commas with line breaks
            echo $line;
            break;
        }
        ++$i; // Increments until line is the one desired by input
    }
    fclose($f);

}
?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it